# Empty data object returns in <Query> after mutation is applied for the same

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

[Github Issue Posted Here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2370#issue-358565324)

```json
"apollo-boost": "^0.1.13",
"apollo-link-context": "^1.0.8",
 "graphql": "^0.13.2",
"graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
"react-apollo": "^2.1.11",
```

**Current Code Structure**

```js
<div>
<Query
    query={FETCH_CATEGORIES_AUTOCOMPLETE}
    variables={{ ...filters }}
    fetchPolicy="no-cache"
  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      console.log('category', loading, error, data); // _______Label_( * )_______
      if (error) return 'Error fetching products';

      const { categories } = data;

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          {categories && (
            <ReactSelectAsync
              {...this.props.attributes}
              options={categories.data}
              handleFilterChange={this.props.handleCategoryFilterChange}
              loading={loading}
              labelKey="appendName"
            />
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }}
  </Query>

<Mutation mutation={CREATE_CATEGORY}>
  {createCategory => (
    <div>
    // category create form
    </div>
  )}
</Mutation>
</div>
```

**Behavior**

Initially, the query fetches data and I get list of categories inside data `given in Label_( * )` . 
After entering form details, the submission occurs successfully. 
`Issue:` Then, suddenly, in the `Label_( * )`, the data object is empty.

How can I solve this?

**Edit**

These are the response:

*Categories GET*

```json
{
  "data": {
    "categories": {
      "page": 1,
      "rows": 2,
      "rowCount": 20,
      "pages": 10,
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "appendName": "Category A",
          "__typename": "CategoryGETtype"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "appendName": "Category B",
          "__typename": "CategoryGETtype"
        }
      ],
      "__typename": "CategoryPageType"
    }
  }
}
```

Category Create

```json
{
  "data": {
    "createCategory": {
      "msg": "success",
      "status": 200,
      "category": {
        "id": "21",
        "name": "Category New",
        "parent": null,
        "__typename": "CategoryGETtype"
      },
      "__typename": "createCategory"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your typedefs?

Comment: @AlessanderFrança I have added response which includes `__typename`

Comment: Queries and mutations that fetch the same entity must query the same fields. This is a way to avoid local cache issues. I'm not sure how it behaves with the "no-cache" policy though. Did you try setting `refetchQueries` on the mutation ?

Comment: Yes, adding `refetchQueries` in the mutation also resulted in same problem. I was using no-cache to fetch the list every time the list component mounts. So that, it always gets newer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing `fetchPolicy` to `cache-and-network`. It solved the issue. [Link to fetchPolicy Documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy)

Doing so, I also had to perform refetch query.

Answer (score 2):

(I came across this question while facing a similar issue, which I have now solved)

In Apollo, when a mutation returns data that is used in a different query, then the results of that query will be updated. e.g. this query that returns all the todos

```
query { 
  todos { 
    id
    description
    status
  }
}
```

Then if we mark a todo as completed with a mutation

```
mutation CompleteTodo {
  markCompleted(id: 3) { 
    todo { 
      id
      status
    }
  }
}
```

And the result is

```
{ 
  todo: {
    id: 3,
    status: "completed"
    __typename: "Todo" 
  }
}
```

Then the todo item with id 1 will have its status updated. The issue comes when the mutation tells the query it's stale, but doesn't provide enough information for the query to be updated. e.g.

```
query {
  todos { 
    id
    description
    status
    owner { 
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
mutation CompleteTodo {
  assignToUser(todoId: 3, userId: 12) { 
    todo { 
      id
      owner {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example result:

```
{ 
  todo: {
    id: 3,
    owner: { 
      id: 12, 
      __typename: "User"
    }, 
    __typename: "Todo"
  }
}
```

Imagine your app previously knew nothing about User:12. Here's what happens

- The cache for Todo:3 knows that it now has owner User:12
- The cache for User:12 contains just `{id:12}`, since the mutation didn't return the name field
- The query cannot give accurate information for the name field for the owner without refetching (which doesn't happen by default). It updates to return `data: {}`

**Possible solutions**

- Change the return query of the mutation to include all the fields that the query needs.
- Trigger a refetch of the query after the mutation (via refetchQueries), or a different query that includes everything the cache needs
- manual update of the cache

Of those, the first is probably the easiest and the fastest. There's some discussion of this in the apollo docs, but I don't see anything that describes the specific behavior of the data going empty.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html

Tip of the hat to @clément-prévost for his comment that provided a clue:

> Queries and mutations that fetch the same entity must query the same
>   fields. This is a way to avoid local cache issues.

Comment: For solution 1st, query `Todo` return an array, but mutation `CompleteTodo` only 1 record, how it can mapping?

Comment: @HuyNguyen Apollo uses a normalised cache. It uses the id and typename to know which object it is, and to update the values of that object in its cache. Then any queries that contain that object anywhere will be updated with the new value

Comment: I just hit this same problem - turns out that data returned from one mutation had one _fewer_ fields than the same type used in the query -> this was causing my query to return an empty data object _after_ updating the cache.

Comment: Since someone commented again on this old question - recent versions of Apollo have a “partialRefetch” option that addresses this